# Outputting a data driven generated graphic which can be modified by the user

Tags: java, php, jquery, graphic

I'm trying to develop a system whereby clients can input a series of plant related data which can then be queried against a database to find a suitable list of plants.

These plants then need to be displayed in a graphic output, putting tall plants at the back and small plants at the front of a flower bed. The algorithm to do this I have set in my mind already, but my question to you is what would be the best software to use that:

1) Allows a user to enter in data

2) Queries a database to return suitable results

3) Outputs the data into a systemised graphic (simple rectangle with dots representing plants)

and the final step is an "if possible" and something I've not yet completely considered:

4) Allow users to move these dots using their mouse to reposition if wanted

--

I know PHP can produce graphic outputs, and I assume you could probably mix this in with a bit of jQuery which would allow the user to move the dots. Would this work well or could other software (such as Java or *_*_) produce a better result?

Thanks and apologies if this is in the wrong section of Stack!

Comment: Assuming this needs to be web based a good javascript programmer could wireframe the basics of this in a few days including sending / receiving data and drag/drop. Making lots of little images stackable is fairly straighforward css and dragging them around can be done also.

Comment: Is it desktop app or web based app?

Comment: The system will be built into a website.

Comment: @JYoung. You should include that in the question, since it changes the requirements completely. I've updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. To answer it directly, any general programming language these days is able to do what you want, with the right libraries - be it C/++, Java, PHP+Javascript, Python, Ruby, and millions of others
With Java in particular, you'll probably want to use the `swing` toolkit for the GUI.

If you do know PHP+Javascript exclusively, it's probably best for your project to stick to what you know. If, however, you see this more as a learning opportunity than a project that needs be done NOW, you could take time to learn a new language in the process.

As to what language to learn, each person has a different opinion, obviously, but generally speaking, a higher-level a language is faster to prototype in.

**EDIT**

If you need this for a website, however, you'll need to use something web based - that is, you'll necessarily have two programs, one that runs server-side, the other one in the client (browser). On the server side, you could very well use PHP, JSP (JavaServer Pages), Python or Ruby. On the client side, you'll be limited to Javascript+DOM (maybe HTML5), a Java applet, or something flash-based.

Comment: Basically clients will be able to input a whole series of parameters related to a flower bed (ie. is it sunlight, shade, size of the bed, soil type, ...) - the system will then list all suitable plants and sort them into a graphic to show how the user might plant their flowers. My idea was to represent flowers as dots to give a general idea and then as the customer knows best, allow them to move these dots to produce something they are happy with.

Comment: @JYoung That sounds like an optimization problem.